# Android Opengl ES Texture compression problem when loading a paletted/atitc DDS (INVALID_ENUM)

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

Currently i'm having a problem loading a DDS compressed texture on OpenGL ES 1.0 on android (generated using The Compressonator): whenever i call glCompressedTexImage2D i get a GL_INVALID_ENUM everytime. Here's the code in question:

```
gl.glCompressedTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, -mipMapCount, GL11.GL_PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES, width, height, 0, tsz, texBuf);
```

The variable `tsz` is calculated as succesive dividing in 4 the pitchOrLinearSize of the texture until it is 1 byte (my textures are square). texBuf is a `ByteBuffer` and mipMapCount. When i do this i obtain a GL_INVALID_ENUM error code and nothing loads. The same occurs when i load the ATC compressed texture (have an adreno gpu).

I'm testing with the Emulator (with paletted textures) and my phone (MSM720x based chipset, equivalent to the HTC Magic, with both types) to no avail.

Here's the complete offending code:

```
                        ByteBuffer texBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tsz);
                        int ld = fis.getChannel().read(texBuf);
                        if (ld == tsz) {
                            int id = newTextureID(gl);
                            gl.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

                            // Set all of our texture parameters:
                            gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
                            gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
                            gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
                            gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);

                            texBuf.position(0);
                            //gl.glCompressedTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, -mipMapCount, GL11.GL_PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES, width, height, 0, tsz, texBuf);
                            gl.glCompressedTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, -mipMapCount, GL11.GL_PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES, width, height, 0, pitchOrLinearSize, texBuf);

                            int err = gl.glGetError();

                            if (err == GL11.GL_INVALID_VALUE) {
                                Log.d("TDL-dds", "Error INVALID_VALUE");
                            } else if (err == GL11.GL_INVALID_ENUM) {
                                Log.d("TDL-dds", "Error INVALID_ENUM");
                            }

                            if (err != 0) {
                                int texs[] = new int[1];
                                texs[0] = id;
                                gl.glDeleteTextures(1, texs, 0);
                                return 0;
                            }
                            return id;
                        }
```

Anyone knows why i'm having that error of INVALID_ENUM?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use 'GL_ATC_RGB_AMD' instead of 'GL_PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES'

Got that from here:: http://www.brokenteapotstudios.com/android-game-development-blog/2011/07/android-atitc-atc-texture-encoding-and-performance.html

Comment: I was trying to implement the same following that tutorial, but to no avail. I was trying to load a paletted texture and an ATC_RGB texture but haven't got any positive result at all. The only way i've found to successfuly load a texture is from the ETC1Util class, and those don't handle alpha channels :-( bummer